# eclipse add objects to class, automatically and retroactively

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I changed the location of a object classes that my class in question relies on.

Now many references to other objects are broken

Is there an automated way for it to add those classes back without my right clicking on every object reference and choosing what the correct coarse of action should be (which is always Import this shockingly matching class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way:

- select all related projects from the **project browser** >> right click >> Source >> Organize imports.

OR

- select all related projects from the **project browser** >> CTRL + SHIFT + O

And next time you want to move a class and automatically all the references, please select the class (right click the class name) and choose the **Refactor** menu item >> **Move..** option.